# Data assign through service not updating in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-services

I wrote a service to share and update Datas between controller

```
myApp.service('Physician',function($http){
 var physicians = [];

 var refresh = function(fetch) {
  physicians = []

  $http({
   url: '/provider/',
   method: 'GET',
  }).success(function (response) {
   $.each(response, function(index, value){
     physicians.push(value);
   });
   console.log(physicians);
  });
 }


return {
 refresh: refresh,
 all: physicians
};
})
```

I included the above service in my controller

```
function physicianController($scope, $http, Physician) {
  $scope.physicians = Physician.all
}
```

Now I have another controller which sharing the Physician service and calling refresh function in it.

```
function conditionController($scope, $http, Physician) {
  $scope.add = function() {
   Physician.refresh();
  }
}
```

As soon as the refresh function is called I expect the  $scope.physicians in physicianController to be the updated, but its not , any tips will be helpful.

Comment: `physicians = []` basically assigns a new reference to the `physicians` variable. AngularJS relies on it to keep the same reference to be able to keep track of changes. You thus need to _empty_ the array, not reinitialize it. `A.splice(0,A.length)` should work.

Comment: you could also assign the service as a scope variable that should work too

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon : Can you give some reference for Service as scope variable , it will be help full :)

Comment: just do $scope.variable=Service;

Comment: you probably need it in to run within an angular digest cycle wrap it in $timeout(function () { ....});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sergiu Paraschiv's Answer : physicians = [] basically assigns a new reference to the physicians variable. AngularJS relies on it to keep the same reference to be able to keep track of changes. You thus need to empty the array, not reinitialize it. A.splice(0,A.length) should work